# Navigating to activity after onStop() is called

Tags: java, android

When `onPause` is called, the `Dialog` is shown and it's background it's transparent so application behind is visible. So if I press Home button while Dialog is shown and then navigate back to application it shows `Dialog` with black background, if I dismiss Dialog application continuous normally. So how do I make background visible after navigating to application. Black background only happens when I press Home button so application is not visible. I'm guessing that something strange happens in `onStop` method...

This is how I call my Dialog:

```
pauseMenu = new PauseMenu();
pauseMenu.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
pauseMenu.show();
```

And onCreate from Dialog class:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.pause_menu);

    }
```

Comment: What do you have in the onStart() and onRestart() method? They are called when you restart your activity. It looks like your dialog box's background color gets reset when these methods are called - did I get that right?

Comment: there is no code in those two methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dialog is recreated automatically, so

```
pauseMenu.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

is not called.
So, try to call this set in your onCreate() after calling super.onCreate()

Comment: this code is actually called in onCreate after I call pauseMenu = new PauseMenu(), so if I try to call it before it throws an error because pauseMenu wasn't inicialized

Comment: You want to call setBackgroundDrawable() in onCreate() method of your dialog class, so it is definitely initialized

Comment: oh, right I thought you mean I should put that in Activity's onCreate method. Now works perfectly, thanks!